# Include file in Podfile

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have an app that consists of many modules which are linked using cocoapods. The linked modules are detected at runtime. Now I want to be able to add and remove modules from the buildserver. What I need to do now is remove or add dependencies to the Podfile before installing.

I think it would be very nice if I could write the depencies in a separate file per target and include those in the Podfile. That way I don't need to modify the Podfile when building. I'm looking for something like the #include preprocessor directive in C but I learned that the include and require functions in ruby work much different. My best success so far was to try `load`but it fails with `Invalid 'Podfile' file: undefined method 'pod' for main:Object.`.

Is there any possibility to include a file?

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if this is supported or not, but it does work if you create a function in your module file which is called from the main Podfile.
Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

use_frameworks!

load 'ModulePods.rb'

abstract_target 'CommonPods' do
    module_pods
    pod 'SAMKeychain'

    target 'Target' do
        pod 'RealmSwift
    end
end
```

ModulePods.rb:

```
def module_pods
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '4.1.0'
end
```

Comment: I can confirm that this is indeed supported.

Answer (score 0):

To take it a few steps further...

We have multiple components that have some common code across all the Podfiles. So, we created a common 'Base Podfile' that all the other Podfiles include.

```
dir=File.dirname(__FILE__);bpf=File.join(dir, 'BasePodfile.rb');tmp=File.join(dir, 'TempPodfile.rb');
system "if curl -s 'https://raw.github.com/<org>/<project>/0.1.0/BasePodfile.rb' -H 'Authorization: Token <auth token>' > #{tmp} ; then mv #{tmp} #{bpf} ; else rm #{tmp} ; fi"
load "BasePodfile.rb"
```

Just use the proper path to the raw file in github (or consume via a similar hosting method).

Then, throw "BasePodfile.rb" into your `.gitignore`, and you're in good shape. Easy to consume common Podfile functionality/changes.